# Executing RXJS Functions in Sequence Defined By Array

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am attempting to execute multiple functions consecutively by defining them in an array (specifically for an Angular APP_INITIALIZER function).

I have this array:

```js
const obsArray = [
    myService1.init(),
    myService2.init(),
    ...
    myServiceN.init()
]
```

Each of these `init()` methods returns `Observable<void>`. Here's an example:

```js
    init() : Observable<void> {
         return this.http.get(this.apiUrl)
             .pipe(
                 // do something with the response
                 switchMap(() => EMPTY)
             );
    }
```

The ``switchMap`statement ensures that the return type is`Observable```.

I've tried this:

```js
    const init$ : Observable<void> = forkJoin(obsArray);
```

But at best it executes the function but not the HTTP call inside. There is no `subscribe()` call since this is inside an Angular factory function assigned to the `APP_INITIALIZER` token.

I've also tried `concatMap()` with no luck.

Is there an rxjs function that will execute each of these consecutively, while waiting for the previous to complete?

I have followed this up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76425788/angular-app-initializer-function-redirects-before-list-of-observables-completes).

Comment: Does something here help: https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-using-app-initializer-di-token-with-observables-and-promises-d089c3127de0

Comment: It looks like you're looking for [`concat()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/concat)

Comment: Oh yeah, `concat` is definitely the solution here. I guess I was overthinking it with my answer below :-o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also put all the observables from the array into an observable, essentially converting `Array<Observable<T>>` to `Observable<Observable<T>>` and then use the higher order function `concatAll`:

```
from(obsArray).pipe(concatAll())
```

Here's a [live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-oxw617?devtoolsheight=60&file=index.ts).

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, recovering from an injury. This seems to do exactly what I need. Thank you for your help.

Comment: I've marked this as completed, but the Angular application seems to not be waiting on the APP_INITIALIZER function this is used in. If anyone can help, I'd appreciate it. Link to followup was edited in to the original question.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the sources provided to `forkJoin` never emit anything.  According to the [docs](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin#:%7E:text=whenever%20any%20of%20the%20given%20observables%20completes%20without%20emitting%20any%20value%2C%20forkJoin%20will%20complete%20at%20that%20moment%20as%20well%20and%20it%20will%20not%20emit%20anything%20either):

> whenever any of the given observables completes without emitting any value, forkJoin will complete at that moment as well and it will not emit anything either

Using `switchMap(() => EMPTY)` actually gives you the type `Observable<never>`. In order to have your `init` methods return `Observable<void>`, you can use `map(() => undefined)` instead:

```js
init(): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl).pipe(
        map(() => undefined)
    );
}
```

This way, the `forkJoin` will receive an emission from each source and emit as expected.