# Angular APP_INITIALIZER Function Redirects Before List of Observables Completes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am using the rxjs `from` function to convert any array of `Observable<void>` members into a single observable which is piped to `concatAll()`:

```js
export const initApplication = (): (() => Observable<any>) => {

  // inject() all services

  const initChain = [
    jwtTokenService.init(),
    myService1.init(),
    myService2.init(),
    ....
    appRouteService.init()
  ];

  return () => from(initChain)
    .pipe(
      concatAll(),
    );

}
```

Unfortunately, the first action taken by the application occurs in `LandingComponent`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-landing',
  template: ''
})
export class LandingComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }

}
```

The attempted navigation to /home occurs before the Observables in the APP_INITIALIZER function complete their tasks (the final observable in the array loads user routes).

The `from()` syntax does ensure that each `init()` function waits for the previous one to complete. But since it doesn't wait for the final Observable to complete, there's a race condition occuring.

Can anyone tell me how to make sure the redirect to /home doesn't occur until after all of the observables in the initApplication function are done?

(This is a followup to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76392269/executing-rxjs-functions-in-sequence-defined-by-array)).

Comment: could you try `return () => forkJoin(initChain);`

Comment: @Andrei it doesn't seem to work. It's like nothing in the list of observables attempts to execute.

Comment: Please show your ngModule providers.  Also, `from(array).pipe(concatAll)` is the same as just using `concat`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is due to the use of the **concatAll** operator.  Once the first inner  observable emits, then the outer observable will emits and the initializer will no longer block.  The easiest solution is to use **forkJoin** which won't emit until all observables complete.

```
export const initApplication = (): (() => Observable<any>) => {
  const initChain = [
    jwtTokenService.init(),
    ....
    appRouteService.init()
  ];

  return forkJoin(initChain);
}
```

If your intention is really to execute the *init* observables sequentially then you can wrap the **concat** operator inside **lastValueFrom** function. This converts the observable to a promise that resolves when the last observable emission occurs.  A promise is a valid return type for an initializer.

```
export const initApplication = (): (() => Promise<any>) => {
  const initChain = [/*...*/];
  return lastValueFrom(concat(...initChain));
}
```

Comment: Observables to promises can be legit in some cases, but most of the time it's a code smell. In this particular case, to remain in a pipeline that is using only observables, instead of using `lastValueFrom`, use `toArray`: https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/toArray I'm saying this because the behavior is also different, instead of only getting the last value, you get all the values that were emitted, which seems more correct in this case

Comment: I ended up getting out a larger hammer and creating a ```CanDeactivate``` route guard to prevent the navigation until the ```init()``` chain sets a "application initialized" flag. I'm eager to see if ```toArray()``` solves the issue.

Comment: I agree that `lastValueFrom` *can* be a sign of code smell - like when somebody converts something to promises because they don't know to something in **rxjs**.  But in this case, is there a practical difference to using `lastValueFrom` vs `toArray`?  It isn't like the emitted value is being used anywhere - it just acts a signal that the initializer is done.  Not only that, but I think `lastValueFrom` gives a bigger indication of intent.  The point is we're waiting for this thing to finish and the results don't matter.  Why needlessly build up an array just to discard it later?